# Show Partial Views on Button Click MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a Main View and Two Partial Views.Main Views Consist of Navigation Links.
PartialViews1 Consist a Button and I need when button click it need to shows the PartialView2

> > PartialView1 has a Button and when i click the button i need to PartialView2(Shoe PartialView2)

### Main View

```
  <div class="container my-3">
    <div class="card">   
<div class="card-header bg-white border-bottom flex-center p-0">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills card-header-pills main-nav-pills" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">CART</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="javascript:void(0)"><i data-feather="arrow-right"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">DELIVERY</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
      <div class="card-body px-1 px-md-5 pt-5">
            @Html.Partial("_PartialView1")
            @*@Html.Partial("_PartialView2)*@

        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

### PartialView1

```
//Some code here
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill btn-lg "id="iddelivery">Delivery<i data-feather="arrow-right"></i></a>
```

### Jquery

```
$("#iddelivery").click(function(){

});
```

Comment: Just wrap the partial view 2 in a hidden div and show it on the click event.  Or you can make an ajax call to get the partial view and load it into an element dynamically.  There are multiple ways to achieve this, depends on your requirements

Comment: The simple way is to render the div in a hidden div and swap the visibility when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Write an action and return PartialView2, write a function to ajax call to that action

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned there are many ways to do it. 
If you don't want to reload/refresh the page with new content the easiest way is to create an ActionResult in your controller and return a partial view.
in your jQuery function the first thing you need to do is to call the preventDefault function to prevent any default action on your button. the next thing is to make a ajax call and receive the view-content from your controller. then you can replace the content of your div with the result you got from controller.